# A Brain Implant improves memory--but how?

Tags: brain

https://www.nytimes.com/2018/02/06/health/brain-implant-memory.html

A new therapy could improve memory by "sending electrical pulses to aid the brain when it is struggling to store new information." I'm trying to figure out how this works physically, in terms of how it actually helps the brain. I would imagine that it has something to do with the neurons getting past the threshold for firing a signal with more ease, but is this because the threshold is suddenly lower because of the presence of the current, or what?

Could anyone provide me with an explanation of the science behind this in lay terms?

Many many thanks

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, when we learn we go over things quite a few times, this is so that our brain goes over the memory cells where we store that information with electrical impulses. Thus when an electrical impulse travels over some branches they strengthen the branches, (I don't know the science behind this). This is what helps us memorise data. So if we ran lots of Impulses over the branches it could help strengthen them or fry your brain, just saying try this in a safe environment such as a lab and not in a homemade electric chair. Also like you said it helps them run easier over the brain which makes it a lot easier to remember things.

Hope this helps,

IbnJalal

Comment: Answers here need to be referenced and based on scientific information, not just ad hoc hypotheses